# Are there any risks with having Django debug tools on production if they are not active?

Tags: django, virtualenv

#### Background

I'd like to install the django-debug-toolbar within my project's virtualenv for local debugging. Since I use a pip-compile/pip-sync process this package will end up installed in my staging and production environments as well. My plan is to only add the settings for django-debug-toolbar (i.e., INSTALLED_APPS, MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, etc) to my local settings file.

#### Question

Does sharing a virtual environment like this introduce any risks or unnecessary overhead on the production server? More generally, what is the optimal balance between separating development and production environments (to keep local tools locally installed) and keeping both environments identical (for accurate testing)?

Answer (score 0):

So after trying this for a few weeks I've discovered only one drawback that is dependent on my testing environment. In certain cases, **the Django debug toolbar can block selenium element clicks** which will cause a previously passing functional test to fail. On the upside, selenium throws an explicit error about this telling you that it can't click on an element because another is blocking so this is pretty easy to catch and fix.

The toolbar is automatically disabled when DEBUG == False, which in production, should always be the case. As far as I can tell there is no serious downside to having this package on a production server.